# Fragment error: XML Binary file: Error inflating fragment class

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

Can anyone help me find the error in this code as it says, it cannot inflate the fragment in the main activity, and by the way, I am new to android. I tried to change the inflating line of code to be the last one in the onCreate function, but it did nothing.

Here is the Code of the activity:

```
 package com.voicenoteinc.tictactou

import android.graphics.Color
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_test.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var tstFragment:TestFragment? = null
    val manager = supportFragmentManager
    val FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragment_tag"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG) != null) {
            tstFragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG) as TestFragment
        }
        if (tstFragment == null) {
            tstFragment = TestFragment()
            manager.beginTransaction().add(tstFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit()
        }

    }
}
```

The XML activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.voicenoteinc.tictactou.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.voicenoteinc.tictactou.TestFragment"
        android:tag="fragment_tag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment class:

```
package com.voicenoteinc.tictactou

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_test.*

class TestFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       retainInstance = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        bu.setOnClickListener { bu.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN) }
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
    }
}// Required empty public constructor
```

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: Probably `bu` is null

Comment: Put your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to add a `Fragment` to an `Activity`.

1. Add it statically like you have done here:

   ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/fragment"
       android:name="com.voicenoteinc.tictactou.TestFragment"
       android:tag="fragment_tag"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test" />
   ```
2. Add it dynamically to a `ViewGroup` like this:

   ```
   ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
   ```

It seems you have attempted to do both here. So you can safely remove all of this code assuming you want to add it statically:

```
// Remove all this code
if (manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG) != null) {
    tstFragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG) as TestFragment
}
if (tstFragment == null) {
    tstFragment = TestFragment()
    manager.beginTransaction().add(tstFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit()
}
```

Explained in detail [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) under `Adding a fragment to an activity`